# duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Tags: r

I have data matrix, it's format is dataframe.#
I want to add rownames(>2000) to it, but I face with this error:

```
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

but I have to have some row with the same name. how can I overcome this problem ? 
is it possible to have same row name with different index like A A1, A3
and R add it automatically ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `make.unique` function

```
make.unique(c('a','a','b','c'))
# [1] "a"   "a.1" "b"   "c"
```